# Adding featureOver on map for multiple layers using carto.js and leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, carto, carto-js-v4

How can I add `featureOver` on map for multiple layers(layers added dynamically) using carto.js and leaflet. This functionality have worked only for one layer. Here is my code:

```js
layer.on(carto.layer.events.FEATURE_OVER, featureEvent => {
  //console.log("feature event", featureEvent);
  popup.setLatLng(featureEvent.latLng);
  if (!popup.isOpen()) {
    popup.setContent(featureEvent.data.sdlbl);
    popup.openOn(map);
  }
});
layer.on(carto.layer.events.FEATURE_OUT, featureEvent => {
  popup.removeFrom(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, CARTO.js does not support feature over multiple layers. I have replicated your problem [in this glitch example](https://glitch.com/~carto-js-feature-over-2-layers). CARTO VL, on the other hand, supports this type of interactivity. You can see a working example [here](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-multi-layer-interactivitiy). You can open a bug ticket in CARTO.js v4 github repository, but that project has not being updated for a while.

Comment: hey ramiroaznar thanks for replying now i have used corto.vl and tried to add label for each layer but i did not found any solution.if you have any idea please tell me

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the piece of code using this time CARTO VL? I need your code to replicate the behavior.

Comment: thanks ramiroaznar .i got solution

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? In doing so you will help the rest of the community.